# ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I am trying to call a java script function from java code.

Here is my Java code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        /**
         * To call a anonymous function from java script file
         */
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
                .getEngineByName("javascript");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/js/MySpec.js");
        engine.eval(fr);

    } catch (ScriptException scrEx) {
        scrEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my java script file:

```
(function() {
  alert("Hello World !!!");
})();
```

But when I run main method of driver class it is giving me error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#2) in <Unknown source> at line number 2
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:110)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:232)
at Java6RhinoRunner.load(Java6RhinoRunner.java:42)
at Java6RhinoRunner.main(Java6RhinoRunner.java:12)
```

What I know is that it need some script engine to execute it.

For that I added rhino.jar file in to my class path.But this is not working.

I an not getting how to solve this error.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `alert("msg");`, try to use `console.log("Msg");` as described [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-referenceerror-alert-is-not-defined). Alert is only defined within a browser.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`alert` is not part of JavaScript, it's part of the `window` object provided by web browsers. So it doesn't exist in the context you're trying to use it in. (This is also true of `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, and other timer-related stuff, FYI.)

If you just want to do simple console output, Rhino provides a `print` function to your script, so you could replace `alert` with `print`. Your script also has access to all of the Java classes and such, so for instance `java.lang.System.out.println('Hello');` would work from your JavaScript script (although it's a bit redundant with the provided `print` function). You can also make Java variables available to your script easily via `ScriptEngine.put`, e.g:

```
engine.put("out", System.out);
```

...and then in your script:

```
out.println('Hello from JavaScript');
```

...so that's a third way to do output from the script. :-)

See the discussion in [the `javax.script` package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html), in particular [`ScriptEngine#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), or for more complex cases, [`Bindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Bindings.html) (and [`SimpleBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/SimpleBindings.html)) and [`ScriptContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html).

Comment: Much like using something like NodeJS, you can execute code but since you are not running in a browser you cannot have the benefits of the browser, such as alert boxes.