# Simulating alerts in Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, alert, sublimetext

I'm running JavaScript from a node.js build I implemented into Sublime Text 3.

From [ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258888/referenceerror-alert-is-not-defined), I understand that since the script isn't run from a browser, `alert` boxes are disabled.

Are there any alternatives to this? I don't mind losing the alert popup, but I want Sublime Text to print out the `alert` and not catch an error on it.

Comment: node.js is a server side framework. How would you show an alert box in the server?

Comment: ... You can name a function whatever you want.

Comment: how about `console.error`? More to the point though, you seem a little confused about what you want. What is your objective here? To suggest a problem to a client of your system, or to log an error for your use?

Comment: An interesting part of ECMAScript is that it has no input or output mechanism, it must be provided by the host environment.

Comment: @DominatorX ... That's quite a bit different. Perhaps you want something ncurses-like? I mean, there's no "alert box" in a console window. Or to interact with Growl or whatever notification mechanism your OS uses?

Comment: if you're just making an application to interact with on the command line, I really don't think you want the interaction you're describing. If you're trying to make a terminal-based but more complicated interaction than tty, you really need to look into an existing framework to support this, as dave says

Comment: @DominatorX But Sublime is Python... You want it to scan the *source* of your JS, and when that *source* is executed, do something?! You *might* be able to do something by having Sublime look at the *output* of your program, but that again is different than what you think you want. I don't really understand; if you're trying to debug, use a debugger. If you're trying to make game elements, then use something that's console.based, e.g., look at Nethack.

Comment: I think you'd be better off to forget emulating 'alert' for a console game and instead get used to dumping errors/debug statements to a log and using a real debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon starting your script ask for the typeof alert and define it if is undefined.

```
if((typeof alert) === 'undefined') {
    global.alert = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.