# calling javaScript from java method

Tags: javascript, java

I want to execute JavaScript function from Java. I used the following piece of code

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();    
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

but this throws an exception for the `alert()` method ?

```
engine.eval("alert('HI');");
```

Comment: Try `eval("alert(\"HI\")");`

Answer (score 2):

So. I'm pretty sure your code here is incorrect.

```
engine.eval("alert(HI);");
```

Try.

```
engine.eval("alert('Hi');");
```

unless you have a variable HI declared.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes around Hi

Comment: can you please give link where i can see some examples/tutorials of using js in java

Answer (score 1):

you can not call javascript from java in any way. javascript is client side language and executed on browser where as java is executed on server

**Update :-**
Thanks guys i learnt something new here.

when i execute the code in op i get below error

```
Error executing script: ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

Reason is alert is not part of JavaScript, it's part of the window object provided by web browsers.so, Nashhorn javascript engine does not know about it.

Please see  [ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258888/referenceerror-alert-is-not-defined)

Comment: It is possible through scripting API, which OP is using: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html

Comment: with help of scripting api we can able to  call  basic javascript but we cant use any predefined method it will throws an exception so if you know any other solution please provide   user3707125

Answer (score 1):

It appears that "alert()" is part of the window object provided by web browsers. [it doesn't exist here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258888/referenceerror-alert-is-not-defined)

I have modified java code:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();      
ScriptEngine engine  = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("print('HI');");
```

This is useful: [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

Information about javscript window object: [The Window Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)

Answer (score -2):

You are doing it the wrong way, you cannot call JavaScript function from java code because one is executed at client side and other at server side...even if you achieve that using some API it's wrong way of architecturing of code.

Comment: I mean it's no different than calling powershell functions with .Net. Or Sql statements...

Comment: Serverside scripting is an elegant thing and can even be sophisticated architecture